# Batch - Can't Access 4th Command Line Argument

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
set major=%~1
set minor=%~2
set build=%~3
set type_number=%~4
echo type_number = %type_number%
```

The above code is trying to get 4 command line arguments and use them later in the code. However, the output from the above is

```
type_number =
```

Additionally, I have an if statement below these definitions

```
if %type_number%==102 (
   goto:begin_RI_build
)
```

which, when in the code, produces `( was unexpected at this time.` and the `type_number =` doesn't even show up.

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

Sorry, should have posted the bigger context of the code. Here it is!

```
set argc=0
for %%x in (%*) do set /A argc+=1
:: Check if there are three arguments
if %argc%==4 (
    :: Check if they are integers
    SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%~1") do set var=%%i
    :: Check if first arg is an integer
    if not defined var ( 
        SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%~2") do set var=%%i 
        if not defined var (
            SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%~3") do set var=%%i 
            if not defined var (
                SET "var="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%~4") do set var=%%i 
                if not defined var (
                    set major=%~1
                    set minor=%~2
                    set build=%~3
                    set type_number=%~4
                    echo major = %major%
                    echo minor = %minor%
                    echo build = %build%
                    echo type_number = %type_number%
                    if %type_number%==102 (
                        goto:begin_RI_build
                    )
                    goto:begin_DI_build
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Please show us the complete code. Is the part you've posted inside a FOR or an IF construct? That would explain the error. What do the parameters look like?

Comment: Hey, sorry for not posting context! I just edited my post. What's weird is that I believe I can access the values of major, minor, etc. in the rest of my code outside this if because it has appeared  to work. Also, the arguments are integers, some multiple digits some not.

Comment: Delayed expansion problem.  See https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html .  Also, quote each side of your `if` comparisons.  `if "!type_number!"=="102"` to avoid problems with undefined variables.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you evaluate every single version element separately?
If you set the elements in front of the code block you need no DelayedExpansion here.

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\07\10\SO_45012850.cmd
@Echo off
Set argc=0
for %%x in (%*) do set /A argc+=1
:: Check if there are three arguments
set "major=%~1"
set "minor=%~2"
set "build=%~3"
set "type_number=%~4"

if %argc%==4 (
    :: Check if they are integers
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in (
      "#%major%.%minor%.%build%.%type_number%#"
    ) do If "%%i" Equ "#...#" (
        echo major = %major%
        echo minor = %minor%
        echo build = %build%
        echo type_#= %type_number%
        if "%type_number%"=="102" (
            goto :begin_RI_build
        )
        goto :begin_DI_build
    )
)
```